# Aggregate Yield to Maturity with Stochastic Interest Rate Paths

Tags: yield, stochastic

Suppose I am valuing a callable bond using stochastic interest rate paths (LMM generated for example) and I wish to express yield to maturity as a single value.

Would it be appropriate to average the cash flows at each time point and determine the yield to maturity for those cash flows (less computationally expensive) or would it be more appropriate to find a yield to maturity for each string of cash flows and average the yield to maturity (more computationally expensive)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you had two curve scenarios, $C_1$ and $C_2$ with probabilities, $p_1$ and $p_2$, then the two ytms under each scenario are:

$$
y_1 = y_1(P_1(C_1)), \; y_2 = y_2(P_2(C_2))
$$

Where the prices of the bond ($P$) are the discounted cashflows under the curves.

Your expected ytm is:

$$E[y]= p_1y_1 + p_2y_2$$

Your question asks if this is equal to evaluating the ytm of the expected prices, i.e.,

$$ E[y] = y(p_1P_1(C_1) + p_2P_2(C_2)) $$

**It is not**.

The ytm function is not homogeneous and it is non-linear, so that,

$$py(P) \ne y(pP)$$

It is quite easy to find a combination of yields and prices such that:

$$
p_1y_1(P_1) + p_2y_2(P_2) \ne y(p_1P_1 + p_2P_2)
$$

proving it is not true in general, and more expensive computational resources are needed in your framework.

**But**

Price is better economic metric, it represents an explicit amount of cash payable for an instrument. YTM is a transformation (and not a great one) so determining the **expected yield** is probably not a good metric. I would perform the analysis to derive an *expected price*. From the expected price you can imply the ytm of the expected price. In my opinion,

$$ \text{ytm of expected price} = y(p_1P_1 + p_2P_2) $$

is better than the,

$$ \text{expected ytm} = p_1y_1(P_1) + p_2y_2(P_2) $$

And less resources are needed for this in your framework.

This is quite easy to visualise given the convexity of the ytm curve relative to price. In the scenario below 3.95 is the ytm of expected price, whereas 4.0 is the expected ytm:

[image]